# $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \mid X \sim U(0,X)$ . Find $f_{X, Y}(x,y)$, $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ and $\Pr(X+Y < 1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \mid X \sim U(0,X)$.

Find:

1. $f_{X, Y}(x,y)$ (The joint probability density function);

   $\mathbb{E}(Y)$;

   $\Pr(X+Y < 1)$.

The only one of these I think I've solved is 2):

$$E(Y)=\int_0^1E(Y \mid x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1\frac{0+x}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac 14.$$

Answer (score 0):

(2) is fine. Maybe a tidier argument would use the property $E(E(Y|X))=E(Y)$. But it's ok (and I suggest that you put a $1$ multiplying $E(Y|x)$ to make clear that you used there the fact that $X\sim U(0,1)$.

For (1), remember that
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_{Y|X=x}(y)\cdot f_X(x).$$

Once you have the joint density you can work on (3), since
$$P(X+Y<1)=\iint_A f_{XY}(x,y) dA,$$
Where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\colon x+y<1\}$. But have in mind the fact that the joint density is $0$ except for a bounded set.

Comment: Would it be okay to do $$P(X+Y<1)=\int_{0.5}^{1} \int_0^{1-x} f_{XY}(x,y) dy dx$$  ??

Comment: You are integrating over the set that satisfies
$$0.5<x<1, \quad 0<y<1-x,$$
and you should integrate over
$$0<x<1,\quad 0<y<x, \quad x+y<1.$$
(0.3,0.2) is in the last, but not on the first. Try to draw both sets and see what you're leaving outside.

Comment: I think I got it.  So I have $$f_{XY}(x,y)= 1/x   $$
Then:

$$ P(X+Y<1)=\int_{0.5}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} 1/x dy dx + \int_{0}^{0.5} \int_{0}^{x} 1/x dy dx  $$

Comment: There you are! One more thing: when you give the answer, remember to mention that $f_{XY}(x,y)=\tfrac1x$ when $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$. But then you used that in (3). Good for you!

Answer (score 0):

1)

$f(x,y)$ must be constant on sets like $\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid y\in(0,x)\}$ and this observation leads to:

$f(x,y)=g(x)$ for $0<y<x<1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Then: $$x=P\left(X\leq x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{u}g\left(u\right)dvdu=\int_{0}^{x}g\left(u\right)udu$$ for $x\in(0,1)$ so we conclude that $g(u)=\frac1u$

So:

$f(x,y)=\frac1x$ for $0<y<x<1$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

2)

$\mathbb EY=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid X]]=\mathbb E\frac12X=\frac12\mathbb EX=\frac12\frac12=\frac14$.

3)

Let $[u+v<1]$ denote the function that takes value $1$ if $u+v=1$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

$\begin{aligned}P\left(X+Y<1\right) & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{u}\left[u+v<1\right]\frac{1}{u}dvdu\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min(u,1-u)}\frac{1}{u}dvdu\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\min\left(u,1-u\right)}{u}du\\
 & =\int_{0}^{0.5}du+\int_{0.5}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)du\\
 & =\int_{0.5}^{1}\frac{1}{u}du\\
 & =\left[\ln u\right]_{0.5}^{1}\\
 & =-\ln0.5\\
 & =\ln2
\end{aligned}
$